# Java, get data types from file in cycle

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

> This file contains characters, string, integer and floating data
>   types. Write a class that has the following features: in the cycle the
>   user introduces the data type (one of: char, String, int, double), in
>   response to an application prints. Console all values corresponding
>   types that exist in the file.

I know how to print all data types. But I dont know how in the cycle the user introduces the data type.

My code:

```
package homework_3;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        int i;
        double d;
        String str;
        char c;

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("test.txt");
        fw.write("Testing Scanner 10 12.2 one c b m");
        fw.close();

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("int: " + sc.nextInt());
            } else if(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("double: " + sc.nextDouble());
            } else {
            str = sc.next();
            if(str.length() == 1) {
                System.out.println("char: " + str);
            } else {
                System.out.println("String: " + str);
                }
            }
            fr.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are deducing the data type from the input so there is nothing for the user to do other than follow your convention.

Comment: " the user introduces the data type." Can you give an example of what you mean?  You don't appear to need this.

Comment: Unrelated to question, but you need to move the `fr.close()` outside the `while` loop, and it should be `sc.close()`.

Comment: You can't manage things with txt file in this way. Why can't you structure your input through XML instead of Text file?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array (or a map) and associate a boolean to all your types. Initialize all value of that array to False. 
Then read your file, and if you find a data of some type, set the boolean associated to true. 
Finally, print all the types associated with a True value

```
    //Initialize your map with the types your looking for
    Map<String, Boolean> mapTypePresentInFile = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    //Set the values to false, because you didn't read your file yet
    mapTypePresentInFile.put("String", false);
    mapTypePresentInFile.put("Integer", false);
    mapTypePresentInFile.put("YourTypeHere", false);

    //Read your file and when you detect the use of a type set the type to true
    //I leave you the task to detect if a type is present
    mapTypePresentInFile.remove("YourTypeHere");
    mapTypePresentInFile.put("YourTypeHere", true);

    //Then you check in your map if the type has been set to true
    for(String type : mapTypePresentInFile.keySet()) {
        if(mapTypePresentInFile.get(type) == true) {
            System.out.println(type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: private boolean int_value(String s) {
                Integer.parseInt(s);
                return true;
        }

that ?

Comment: I edited my answer, with some code samples. Replace YourTypeHere by whatever type you wanna print. There you have a basic algo, you still need to detect the type your looking for.

Comment: i make that with scanner. thanks. but how i corresponding types that exist in the file "test.txt" ?

Comment: In a text file, you store only strings. Detecting the type out of a string is difficult and non trivial. You cannot for exemple differenciate a char from a string, because string are composed by ... chars. The same apply to ciffers and numbers, because number are composed by ciffers.